# Oft DeadlineExceededErrors when yaml.load() on google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, timeout

My app at google-app-engine uses a yaml settings file. I've used the same approach in several similar app engine apps for a couple of years. App settings that do not have to change unless at deployment time go into that yaml file.

Now opening and loading from that yaml file turned out to be a big source of problem if I had a bunch of users going at the API at the same time. So I quickly fixed the issue some year or two ago by memcaching the contents of the yaml. That worked well for a long time.

I realized recently that I still get occasional DeadlineExceededErrors errors when trying to open() that file. The number of open attempts should be very few (when I manually change the key used for the memcache really, which should be even less than amount of deployments). What really happens, sometimes, is that it times out after 60 seconds, failing to open that file - this happens when the memcache for some reason has lost the content pertaining to that key. That's okay because that's how Memcache works, it still keep the memcached stuff around most of the time. I just use it for that yaml file and never felt a need to use it for anything else. Still, the open() often fails out after 60 seconds, with a DeadlineExceededErrors.

Any leads?

The error log goes like this:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~mjpuroland/1.385586677613659867/mjconfig.py", line 81, in loadversionsettings
    versionsettings = yaml.load(open(versionsettingsfile).read())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 82, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_sequence_node(anchor)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 111, in compose_sequence_node
    node.value.append(self.compose_node(node, index))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/scanner.py", line 159, in fetch_more_tokens
    self.stale_possible_simple_keys()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10/yaml/scanner.py", line 283, in stale_possible_simple_keys
    for level in self.possible_simple_keys.keys():
DeadlineExceededError
```

Update: Looking at the log again, I realized that what is timing out is the *yaml.load()* part, *not* open(). Is yaml that problematic? The yaml file I have is 249 KB at the moment.

Comment: A complex yaml file could take quite some time to load.  I would put some logging around the load and see how long it normally takes.  If multiple threads on the same instance are all trying to do this at the same time, then you could be running into the dogpile effect.  (all piling in at the same time). I suggest you run a job every few minutes to explicitly keep the cache up to date.  Or even stop using a yaml file.  Read the file, and pickle its contents and persist it in the datastore, that will be quicker than parsing a big yaml file all the time.

Comment: Ok I guess 250 KBis a bit too much. The end user client using the API which ultimately use the data in the settings file, often sends requests in bursts of three and whenever the memcache is empty this will make the app engine attack the yaml three times within a second or so. Yes it sounds like I should put the data in the data store or something like you suggest. Always had good response with the datastore so far. I could redesign the client but fixing the issue on the server side could prevent similar issues in a better way.

Comment: I introduced an "intermediate" cache in the datastore, it sits between memcache and the yaml, see how things go. It will be slow hopefully only the first access after deployment/change of key for cache. I like to keep the data in yaml ultimately because I can git that easily :-P

Comment: Sounds like a go, I would preparse and then store the structure as a blob in the datastore.  Use another handler to parse and store the yaml in the datastore and only trigger that when you push/deploy. Then you can copy the structure from the datastore to memcache directly.

Comment: Could you load the yaml file at the highest level of you python file so that it is loaded only when an instance is spun up and the data is stored in the instance memory in a module variable?

Comment: That would be a good performing option. (load and parse yaml during a warmup request).